# Java Garbage Collector Issues, Multiple Full GC in a short

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Currently we are having massive problems with memory on our servers. They run out of memory in under an hour sometimes. We have a 256gb server and a E5-1650 v3 Hexa-Core from hetzner. Here is the garbage collection log. 
https://pastebin.com/7NUEGQs1
`public void run(){}` It made me put code here even though this question is about memory leaks and garbage collection

I don't think it ever clears any objects from the old generation, AND why the hell is the allocated memory going down from 10gb to 9.3gb when its literally starving.

I have tried everything to fix this, I even reset my server to factory default and reinstalled everything. It could be a memory leak I don't know. This seems incredibly strange even if it's a memory leak. it should never run that many full gcs that quickly.

Also another thing we noticed is when we stop one server, the other 3 begin to crash as well. Could this be a ram problem since each of the four servers is allocating 8-10 gb.

does this mean that no old gen objects are being deleted?

3978.597: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1165312K->647763K(2330112K)] [ParOldGen: 6990613K->6990765K(6990848K)] 8155925K->7638529K(9320960K), [Metaspace: 41441K->41441K(1087488K)], 3.7144066 secs] [Times: user=34.89 sys=0.09, real=3.71 secs]

regardless of my applications something must be very wrong for it to clear 150kb out of 6gb of old gen data right?

ParOldGen: 6990613K->6990765K(6990848K)

Comment: Try to monitor your server with JVisual or JConsole to see what is triggering a lot of GC, When it is being triggered. If a Memory leaks happens then you need to see YOUR APPLICATION and see with JProfiler to see where is the memory leak. Java is trying to defend of your bad performance of your app.

Comment: You do understand that your question qualifies for the vaguest question of the day? Memory leaks are complicated and time consuming problems, and we don’t know jack about your applications

Comment: 3978.597: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1165312K->647763K(2330112K)] [ParOldGen: 6990613K->6990765K(6990848K)] 8155925K->7638529K(9320960K), [Metaspace: 41441K->41441K(1087488K)], 3.7144066 secs] [Times: user=34.89 sys=0.09, real=3.71 secs] doesnt this mean it is  running a  full gc and not clearing any old gen objects all at??

Comment: What did you change that triggered the change in behavior? Updated Application? Changed hardware? Jave version? JVM or GC Settings? We can't help without information.

Comment: nothing, it has'nt worked since day 1.

Comment: OK so we're talking about a new system that never worked yet?

Comment: correct, we are trying a new host today aswell. we use redis, mysql, and our java application.

Comment: I suppose your app did work on some development system before being deployed to this one?

Comment: How much of the data can be freed in a GC cycle depends on the application. It seems not much is eligible for collection in your case. This may mean you've got a memory leak. It can also mean that your application just requires even more memory to operate correctly - we don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: *"doesnt this mean it is running a full gc and not clearing any old gen objects all at?"* I think you are correct. (See Hulk's comment for two most likely explanations.)

Comment: *"Full GC (Ergonomics)"* - those GCs are triggered by GC ergonomics, not by allocation failures. You should add the JVM options you're using to the question. And maybe add logging for those with `-XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=1`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is perfectly correct, but it doesn't reflect some untrue assumptions you stated:

> When a young evacuation is processed objects are visited through references starting from the roots to find out unreachable ones.

No, the unreachable ones won't get ever reached. That's the key to efficiency, as most newly created objects are unreachable when the GC runs. It only deals with reachable objects, copies them to a Survivor Space and what's left is free memory. *The GC has no idea how many unreachable objects it's left behind.* It simply doesn't care.

*Actually, the "garbage collector" should be called "non-garbage rescuer" as that's what it does*

> As a result, ALL objects are considered, including objects allocated in Old Generation are also visited and marked if they are reachable.

No. Unreachable objects in Eden and Survivor Spaces won't ever get touched(*).

Objects in the Old Generation get only touched if they're in the *remembered sets* as Holger explained. This includes also unreachable objects in the Old Generation, as during a minor GC we don't know which old objects are still reachable (usually, most of them are).

> As I understand reclaiming Young Generation and Old Generation at once is demanding because these generations are located in different contiguous parts of memory.

No. Major GC is demanding as the Old Generation is big.

---

(*) Objects implementing `finalize` or extending `Reference` need special handling when they become unreachable.